# How do I set factor levels to the order they appear in a data frame?

Tags: r

I want to create a heat map using ggplot however I want to order the y-axis by the number of observations. I order the dataframe by the column N and add the number of observations to the group name so that it appears in the axis label. When I plot the data it re-orders based on the group name. Is there a way to set factor levels based on the order they appear in the data frame?

Some data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

school <- c("School A", "SChool B", "School C", "School D", "School E", "School F")
N <- c(25,28,12,22,30,25)
var1 <- c(1,0,1,1,0,1)
var2 <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1)
var3 <- c(0,1,0,1,1,1)

df <- tbl_df (data.frame (school, N, var1, var2, var3))

df <- arrange (df, N) %>%
  gather (variable, value, var1:var3)

df$school <- paste0 (df$school, " (", df$N, ")")

df <- select (df, school, variable, value)

ggplot(df, aes(variable, school)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue")
```

Ultimately I want the order of schools to be:

School C (12)

School D (22)

School A (25)

School F (25)

School B (28)

School E (30)

As I want to do this for multiple plots I want to find a way to do this automatically and not have to re-set factor levels each time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way around this is to change your `ggplot` call to

```
ggplot(df, aes(variable, factor(school, levels = unique(school)))) + ...
```

To avoid typing this every time, you can create a function

```
f <- function(x) factor(x, levels = unique(x))
```

and then call it by `ggplot(df, aes(variable, f(school))) + ...`

Note that this will place the first level of the factor at the bottom of the plot. If you want it at the top, you need to change `f` to `function(x) factor(x, levels = rev(unique(x)))`

Comment: How does `factor(school, levels = unique(school))` change the result, compared to just `factor(school)`? I can see it does, but how does it link the order to the value **N**?  And `factor(df$school) == factor(df$school2, levels = unique(df$school2))` returns a vector `TRUE` of length 18 - how can that be so and yet have different results on the ggplot?

Comment: @James `factor()` does by default first sort the levels (alphabetically) -> see the documentation `?factor`. If we use `factor(school, levels = unique(school))`, we force the levels to be in the order they appear in the vector, i.e. without first being sorted.

You can have a look at the following example, where we start with an (alphabetically) unsorted vector:

`school_rev <- c( "School C", "School B", "School A")`

You'll notice the different order of the levels of: `f1 <- factor(school_rev)` and `f2 <- factor(school_rev, unique(school_rev))`.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following `forcats` pipe to the code just before the call to `ggplot()`.

```
library(forcats)
df$school <- fct_inorder(df$school) %>% fct_rev()
```

`fct_inorder()` creates factor levels in data frame order and `fct_rev()` reverses them so the plot goes in the right direction.

Comment: This worked well for my use case of ordering a character based on another field with the "duplicate" levels that couldn't be applied to a factor. I ended up sorting my data using `arrange` followed by this code. Now I can get back to this complicated plot!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to make the `school` column and ordered factor:

```
df$school <- reorder(df$school, rep(6:1, length.out=length(k)), order=TRUE)
```

[image]