# ggplot doesn't plot the order of the data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

If I have a `head(df)` like:

```
    feature Comparison   Primary       diff key
1     work  15.441176 20.588235  5.1470588   1
2 employee  22.794118 19.117647 -3.6764706   2
3     good  11.029412 11.764706  0.7352941   3
4  improve   8.088235 10.294118  2.2058824   4
5   career   2.941176  8.823529  5.8823529   5
6  manager   2.941176  8.823529  5.8823529   6
```

and I'm trying to plot something with:

```
 p = ggplot(x, aes(x = feature,size=8)) + geom_point(aes(y = Primary)) +
        geom_point(aes(y=Comparison)) + coord_flip()
      ggplotly(p)
```

Is there something I'm missing that causes `p` not to plot the order of the data above? the first five on the plot are

```
work
train
time
skill
people
```

But according to the df, it should be work, employee, good, improve, career.

Comment: Does something like this work for you? `x$feature <- factor(x$feature, levels = rev(x$feature))`. Also, `train`, `time`, `skill`, `people` are all not in your sample data

Comment: What is the structure of `feature`?  If it's a factor, it may already have a particular order assigned.  If you want a particular order, it's usually easiest to add levels to your data or to re-order a factor

Comment: `Feature` is a `chr` not a factor. Train, time, skill, people are further down in the `df`. I posted the `head(df)`

Comment: It seems to me the second solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469612/how-do-i-set-factor-levels-to-the-order-they-appear-in-a-data-frame#26470381) would work, using `fct_inorder()` in your ggplot call like this: `p = ggplot(x, aes(x = fct_inorder(feature), size = 8)) + geom_point(aes(y = Primary)) +
     geom_point(aes(y = Comparison)) + coord_flip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these things called "levels" which ggplot uses to determine the order things should appear in the plot. If you ran `levels(x$feature)` in the console, then I bet the list you see has the same order as what appears in the plot.

To have them show up in the order you want, you can just have to override the "levels" for the feature column.

```
x$feature = factor(x$feature, levels = c("work",
                                         "employee",
                                         "good",
                                         "improve",
                                         "manager"))
```

Comment: feature isn't a factor. feature are just `chr`. If I do levels(x$feature) I get NULL. and if I do is.factor(x$feature) = FALSE

Comment: Oh, okay. My bad on that. The above code should still work though. It converts to x$feature to factors and sets the levels.

Comment: I'm using a function prior that sorts the df based on Primary then Comparison. This is also in a Shiny app, so df is reactive and changes, so hardcoding levels isn't possible.

Comment: Combing your solution with Mike H. comment works though.